# Change the Wordpress default landing page( listing posts ) to a page (like about,contact)

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Can i able to change the default landing page of my wordpress blog from 'mydomain.com' to a page 'mydomain.com/about'

By default in wordpress, 'mydomain.com' shows up with the list fo blog posts, but rather I need a page 'domain.com/about' to be my default landing page and using some link i need the blog posts to shown. Is it possible to change it??? if so how???...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your dashboard got to settings (bottom left sidebar) and then under the reading tab there are options to change your front page.

Comment: is there any filter for the front page? I want to set custom link as home page (according to certain conditions home page will be changed)

Answer (score 2):

read this

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

http://bloggingexperiment.com/archives/wordpress-page-as-home-page.php

and you can ask worpress questions here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/